# Reading images from memory in Android ICS not working

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a program which retrieves the images from the Gallery. Here is my code:

```
String[] id = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
int image_col_index = imageCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
int count = imageCursor.getCount();
//in a loop the below code goes {
    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
    imageCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    int id = imageCursor.getInt(image_col_index);
    i.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""+ id));
    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    //here I am storing this image i to a list for further use
}//here loop ends
```

The above code works fine in **Emulator** as well as in **Galaxy S** with **Android 2.2 or 2.3**. But now when I run it in **Galaxy Nexus**, it fails to read images from memory.

The only difference is Galaxy Nexus is running in **Android 4.0** and is not supporting **SDCard** instead it has an internal storage of 13 GB.

So my question is what should I change in the above code so that it could run on Nexus.

I am thinking that as Nexus does not support external storage, so it could be solved by changing the URI from `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` to `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`. Will this work for me or I have to do something else. Please guide me.

Comment: Why tell us where the loop is instead of simply writing `while` or `for`? We're all programmers here.

Comment: BTW, your question content looks a lot cleaner when you only **bold** each keyword the first time you use it and nothing after that. Otherwise everything looks bold and it loses the emphasis :)

Comment: @AlexLockwood thanks for the guiding me on this formatting approach. Now please give me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> The only difference is Galaxy Nexus is running in Android 4.0 and is
>   not supporting SDCard instead it has an internal storage of 13 GB.

And you are trying to read from external storage :)

Change

```
i.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""+ id));
```

To

```
i.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""+ id));
```